# I am trying to update the state but it's not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-state

I want to update my "userSuccessfullLoggedIn" in success login state but it won't updating. It update the state if username and password are incorrect but it is not updating when username and password are true I cant find the problem please help me.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import LoginResponse from "./LoginResponse";

class Login extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      username: "",
      password: "",
      loginStatus: "",
      userSuccessfullLoggedIn: "",
    };
  }

  onChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    });
  };

  loginResponse = () => {
    if (this.state.username === "jarvis" && this.state.password === "jarvis") {
      console.log("Successfull");
      this.setState({
        loginStatus: true,
        userSuccessfullLoggedIn: true,
      });
      sessionStorage.setItem("user", this.state.username);
      this.props.history.push(`/welcome/${this.state.username}`);
    } else {
      console.log("Wrong");
      this.setState({
        loginStatus: false,
        userSuccessfullLoggedIn: false,
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="login-form">
          <h1 className="text-center"> LOGIN </h1>
          <div className="form-group">
            <input
              placeholder="Username"
              className="form-control"
              type="text"
              name="username"
              value={this.state.username}
              onChange={this.onChange}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <input
              placeholder="Password"
              className="form-control"
              type="password"
              name="password"
              value={this.state.password}
              onChange={this.onChange}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.loginResponse}>
              LOGIN
            </button>
          </div>
          <LoginResponse status={this.state.loginStatus} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Login;
```

**Console**

[image]

It is going inside Success block but it is not updating the state from false to true

Comment: Works for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-chaum-542c6?file=/src/App.js

Comment: setState is async in nature, put a call back and check the status what you are getting 
i.e this.setState({
        loginStatus: true,
        userSuccessfullLoggedIn: true,
      }, () => { console.log(this.state.loginStatus); });

Answer (score 1):

setState is async in nature, put a call back and check the status what you are getting i.e

```
this.setState({ loginStatus: true, userSuccessfullLoggedIn: true, }, () => {
 console.log(this.state.loginStatus); 
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.Now I understand why It is not updating the state.